# Run net view command through jsp

Tags: java, jsp

The following code runs successfully via a .java file but will not run if I try to run it through a .jsp file.

If I remove the IP address and domain it runs successfully.

I included <%@ page import="java.io.*" %> on the jsp page. Any help will appreciated. Thank you.

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "net", "view", "IPADDRESSHERE", "/domain:DOMAIN"};

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(commands);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String strLine;

while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)   {    
System.out.println(strLine);
}
```

TestServlet.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public TestServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec("net view SHARENAMEGOESHERE");
    pr.wait();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("networklist.properties", false));

    String [] nextLine;
    String strLine;
    String copied;
    String newString = null;
    StringBuilder toFile = new StringBuilder();                 

    while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)   {

        out.println(strLine+"<br>");    

       if(strLine.indexOf("Print") != -1){

           copied = strLine;                   
           copied = copied.replaceAll("\\s+", "");                 
           nextLine = copied.split("Print");

           if(nextLine.length == 2){                       
               newString = nextLine[1] + "=" + nextLine[0]+"\n";
               toFile.append(newString); 
               out.println(newString+"<br>");
           }                   
       }
    }


    if(null != newString){
        output.write(toFile.toString());
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }


}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request,response);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you well aware that this piece of code executes the command on the server machine (where the webserver and Java/JSP code runs), not on the client machine (where the webbrowser and JSP-generated HTML code runs)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't run it in a JSP. Do that in a `HttpServlet` and invoke it from the JSP if needed. JSP is not meant to have complicated java code inside it for this precise reason - it is hard to debug and identify problems.

Comment: I was just testing something, I did import java.io.* and I used out.print for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might have missed some import statement.

Also one more thing, are you trying to print read file on the screen??
then you should use out.println instead of System.out.println.
System.out.println will print on console and not on the page.

Hope this helps.

Still my advice will also be the same that you should move this code to some proper class either servlet or some utility class.

Comment: created a servlet and still no luck at all. From the command line the code works like a charm and once I try to run it through the servlet it doesn't work at all.

Comment: How are you running it? You deployed servlet on some server? And can you please share code of the servlet you have written. And just to confirm, you want the output to come on the browser calling the servlet/jsp or is it something else you want?

Comment: please checkout the servlet above. The servlet is deployed through a war file and runs on tomcat. You can find the code at https://gist.github.com/1789774